# BootStrap Age Input Form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a form in HTML that will validate a user's age. The user will need to be be over 21 years old. If the user is over 21 then they are redirected to the slash page.

The age form will consist of having a drop down selection for values.

- Value Drop Down "Month" will print out 1-12 (to account for each month of the year)
- Value Drop Down "Day" will print out 1-31 (to account for each month that has 31 days)
- Value Drop Down "Year" will print out Years.

I have experience doing this with VBA and wanted to know to begin approaching this with Bootstrap and HTML

Comment: Do you mean Date of Birth?

Comment: You need Javascript or PHP/ASP to get the result, mere HTML or Bootstrap wont help

Comment: Would JQuery also be able to achieve the same results?

Comment: Hello I was able to find a post related http://michaelsoriano.com/jquery-plugin-check-user-age/ appreciate all the help. I will come back and work on building the splash page next.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want you to clear that HTML is not a programming language so you can't use logical statements in HTML;

You need to use either JS(javascript) or any backend language(***JS is also used as backend***);

After applying backend you can render that page to the slash page to redirect and use pickers from the bootstrap [library](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or Materializecss [library](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html);

As you wish, if you still want to choose a dropdown button go ahead and use select option tap;